# Hudson, publish artifact to a windows file share?

Tags: build-process, hudson

We've set up Hudson to do nightly builds of some Vs2008 C++ projects. How can we configure hudson to publish the artifacts to a file share ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run the Hudson service under an account that has access to the resource and perform the copy in our Ant scripts.

The [CopyArchiver plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/CopyArchiver+Plugin) was available when we set this up, but it looks like it might do the job.

Note, you may also have to look at how to get those artifacts into other projects.  Again, we use Ant.  Within our build.xml files we have GetPublishedArtifacts and GetLocalArtifacts tasks to allow the developer to get artifacts differently when building in their own environments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you browsed the [artifact uploaders](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins#Plugins-Artifactuploaders) section of the Hudson Wiki?  It lists several plugins that can accomplish this, depending on your local network setup.